# SQL Query to fetch the latest payment method and invoice date

Tags: sql, oracle

There are four tables

First - Customer
Second - Invoice
Third - Supplier
Fourth - Supplier_Remit

Tables details are mentioned below

| Customer_id | Customer_Account_number | Customer_Status | Supplier_id | Supplier_Remit_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1501 | Active | 11 | 111 |
| 2 | 1502 | Inactive | 12 | 112 |
| 3 | 1503 | Active | 13 | 113 |
| 4 | 1504 | Active | 14 | 114 |
| 5 | 1505 | Inactive | 15 | 115 |

| Invoice_Date | Invoice_Amount | Invoice_Number | Payment Method | Customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 100 | 1000001 | Cash | 1 |
| 12/01/2022 | 150 | 1000002 | Credit Card | 1 |
| 11/09/2022 | 200 | 1000003 | Credit Card | 1 |
| 12/09/2022 | 300 | 1000004 | Cash | 2 |
| 04/15/2022 | 1000 | 1000005 | Cash | 2 |
| 04/15/2022 | 1000 | 1000006 | Credit Card | 3 |
| 10/31/2022 | 250 | 1000007 | Cash | 4 |
| 10/25/2022 | 250 | 1000008 | Cash | 4 |
| 09/20/2022 | 130 | 1000009 | Credit Card | 5 |
| 05/20/2022 | 120 | 10000010 | Credit Card | 5 |

| Supplier_Name | Supplier_id |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 11 |
| ACCC | 12 |
| ADEF | 13 |
| AJKL | 14 |
| AFLR | 15 |

| City | Country | Supplier_Remit_id | Supplier_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boston | US | 111 | 11 |
| Oak | US | 112 | 12 |
| Albany | US | 113 | 13 |
| Madison | US | 114 | 14 |
| Los Ang | US | 115 | 15 |

I need help in finding the most recent payment method, most recent invoice amount, no of count of invoices missing for current year (2023) and no of count of invoices missing for previous year(2022)

I have written query to find first few columns but unable to write further to get the above mentioned details

```
select c.customer_id,c.customer_account_number,c.customer_status,sr.country,max(i.invoice_date) as Latest receieved_Invoice_date
from 
customer c,
invoice i,
supplier s,
supplier_Remit sr
where 
c.customer_status='Active' and
sr.supplier_id=s.supplier_id and
c.supplier_remit_id=sr.supplier_remit_id and
c.customer_id=i.customer_id
group by
c.customer_id,c.customer_account_number,c.customer_status,sr.country;
```

My expected output would be as below

| Customer_id | Cust_Acct_Num | Cust_Status | Country | Last_Inv_Rec_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1501 | Active | US | 01/01/2023 |
| 3 | 1503 | Active | US | 04/15/2022 |
| 4 | 1504 | Active | US | 10/31/2022 |

| Latest_Paym_Method | Lastest_Inv_Amt | Count of Missing Inv for Curr Yr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cash | 100 | 0 |
| Credit card | 1000 | 1 |
| Cash | 250 | 1 |

| Count of Missing Invoices for Prev Year |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 11 |

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output?

Comment: When asking questions involving that many tables and so many rows of sample data, providing a fiddle link and showing the intended outcome will increase the chances to get a helpful answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "invoices missing" ?

Comment: @PaulW - invoices missing means invoices not received in a particular month

Comment: @lemon - pls check the output edited in the question and let me know if you need any further details

Comment: @JonasMetzler I have edited the post with the expected output

Comment: Is your output one table or three? If it's one table, what happened to the other two customers?

Comment: @lemon my output has 9 columns from different tables mentioned above. The output i am looking is for active customers so other two customers are inactive hence the output had 3 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MAX(...) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY invoice_date)` to get values for the latest invoice and conditional aggregation to count the number of months where there are invoices and then subtract from the total number of months to find the missing invoices:

```sql
SELECT c.Customer_id,
       c.Customer_Account_number,
       c.Customer_Status,
       r.country,
       i.last_invoice_date,
       i.latest_payment_method,
       i.latest_invoice_amount,
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) - COALESCE(i.missing_invoices_this_year, 0)
         AS missing_invoices_this_year,
       12 - COALESCE(i.missing_invoices_last_year, 0)
         AS missing_invoices_last_year
FROM   customer c
       INNER JOIN supplier_remit r
       ON (c.supplier_id = r.supplier_id)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT customer_id,
                MAX(invoice_date) AS last_invoice_date,
                MAX(payment_method) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY invoice_date)
                  AS latest_payment_method,
                MAX(invoice_amount) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY invoice_date)
                  AS latest_invoice_amount,
                COUNT(
                  DISTINCT
                  CASE
                  WHEN invoice_date <  SYSDATE
                  AND  invoice_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY') 
                  THEN TRUNC(invoice_date, 'MM')
                  END
                ) AS missing_invoices_this_year,
                COUNT(
                  DISTINCT
                  CASE
                  WHEN invoice_date <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY') 
                  AND  invoice_date >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'), -12)
                  THEN TRUNC(invoice_date, 'MM')
                  END
                ) AS missing_invoices_last_year
         FROM   invoice
         GROUP BY customer_id
       ) i
       ON (c.customer_id = i.customer_id)
WHERE  c.customer_status = 'Active';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer (Customer_id, Customer_Account_number, Customer_Status, Supplier_id, Supplier_Remit_id) AS
SELECT 1, 1501, 'Active',   11, 111 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1502, 'Inactive', 12, 112 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1503, 'Active',   13, 113 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1504, 'Active',   14, 114 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1505, 'Inactive', 15, 115 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE invoice (Invoice_Date, Invoice_Amount, Invoice_Number, Payment_Method, Customer_id) AS
SELECT DATE '2023-01-01',  100,  1000001, 'Cash',        1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-12-01',  150,  1000002, 'Credit Card', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-11-09',  200,  1000003, 'Credit Card', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-12-09',  300,  1000004, 'Cash',        2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-15', 1000,  1000005, 'Cash',        2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-15', 1000,  1000006, 'Credit Card', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-31',  250,  1000007, 'Cash',        4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-25',  250,  1000008, 'Cash',        4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-09-20',  130,  1000009, 'Credit Card', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-05-20',  120, 10000010, 'Credit Card', 5 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE supplier (Supplier_Name, Supplier_id) AS
SELECT 'ABC',  11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ACCC', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ADEF', 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AJKL', 14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AFLR', 15 FROM DUAL;

 
CREATE TABLE supplier_remit (City, Country, Supplier_Remit_id, Supplier_id) AS
SELECT 'Boston',  'US', 111, 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Oak',     'US', 112, 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Albany',  'US', 113, 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Madison', 'US', 114, 14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Los Ang', 'US', 115, 15 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_NUMBER | CUSTOMER_STATUS | COUNTRY | LAST_INVOICE_DATE | LATEST_PAYMENT_METHOD | LATEST_INVOICE_AMOUNT | MISSING_INVOICES_THIS_YEAR | MISSING_INVOICES_LAST_YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1501 | Active | US | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | Cash | 100 | 0 | 10 |
| 3 | 1503 | Active | US | 2022-04-15 00:00:00 | Credit Card | 1000 | 1 | 11 |
| 4 | 1504 | Active | US | 2022-10-31 00:00:00 | Cash | 250 | 1 | 11 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qxnoA1KA)

Comment: I could see that if there are multiple invoice payment for a given customer id then the query picks up the first entry received in the payment method rather than the last entry. Is there a way to find out the last payment method receipt

Comment: @Divaansh It does return the last entry. For `customer_id` the date `2023-01-01` is after the other two so it is the last (latest). If you want to find the first (earliest) then use `MIN(invoice)date)` and `MAX(payment_method) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY invoice_date)`.

Comment: Suppose if a particular customer id has received two invoices and both invoices have same invoice date but with different payment method then which entry would it pick up based on the MAX and dense rank last ?

Comment: @Divaansh Evaluate it from right-to-left `ORDER BY invoice_date` then `KEEP` the rows that are `RANK`ed  `FIRST` and, from those kept rows, return the `MAX(payment_method)`. So in your example, it would return the maximum of the two values that both have the earliest date.

Comment: @MT0- Can you please help me to add Supplier Name to the query output

Comment: @Divaansh Just `INNER JOIN` the `suppliers` table and then include `supplier_name` in the outer `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find what's missing, you have to first define what should be there, so you need to create a calendar of every month. Then you can use outer joins to the invoice table to find where there aren't any records for that month for that customer. There are lots of ways to write SQL to do this. Here's one:

```
WITH months AS(SELECT /*+ MATERIALIZE */ *
                 FROM (SELECT 'Current' year,
                              ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY'),ROWNUM-1) month_start
                         FROM [any table with at least 12 rows]
                        WHERE ROWNUM <= 12)
                 WHERE month_start < SYSDATE
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 'Previous' year,
                      ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12),'YYYY'),ROWNUM-1)
                 FROM [any table with at least 12 rows]
                WHERE ROWNUM <= 12)
SELECT customer.*,
       inv.invoice_amount most_recent_invoice_amount,
       inv.payment_method most_recent_payment_method,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM months,
               invoice
         WHERE months.year = 'Current'
           AND months.month_start = TRUNC(invoice_date(+),'MM')
           AND invoice.customer_id(+) = customer.customer_id
           AND invoice.customer_id IS NULL) missed_current_year_months,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM months,
               invoice
         WHERE months.year = 'Previous'
           AND months.month_start = TRUNC(invoice_date(+),'MM')
           AND invoice.customer_id(+) = customer.customer_id
           AND invoice.customer_id IS NULL) missed_previous_year_months 
  FROM customer
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT invoice_amount,
                           payment_method
                      FROM (SELECT invoice_amount,
                                   payment_method,
                                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY invoice_date DESC) seq
                              FROM invoice
                             WHERE invoice.customer_id = customer.customer_id)
                     WHERE seq = 1) inv
```

Comment: `(+)` joins? Why not use the ANSI join syntax as it has been around for at least 20 years and is much less confusing, (Also, the OP is likely going to get `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` as they do not have a `rows_86400` table.)

Comment: Fixed the rows_86400. (+) because it works better in Oracle than ANSI joins. They take hints a lot more obediently, so that's what I default to. It doesn't matter, a person can write it either way.

Comment: @PaulW when i run the query its working fine but there are certain instances where  particular customer id has received two different invoices on the same day and both invoices have same invoice date but with different payment method so when the query runs which has seq 1 the first entry payment method is picked but i need the payment method which was received later in this case the second invoice so in this case the query fails to pick the latest invoice payment method. Can you pls suggest any other way ?

Comment: Sure, just adjust the ORDER BY parameters to what you need. For example: "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY invoice_date DESC, received_date DESC, invoice_id DESC) seq" ... whatever it takes to get the row you want assigned seq = 1.

Comment: @PaulW Thank you so much. The query now is working fine.